# Relation between degree of polynomial and no. Of positive roots

Tags: functions

Is there any relationship between degree of polynomial and no. Of positive roots of the equation??

As far as I concern polynomial of degree n has atmost n distinct roots. But is there any implications of positive roots??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A polynomial of degree $n$ can always have $n$ negative roots. Consider $f(x)=(x+1)^n$.

Comment: I have a function y=2x^3-x^2+2x-5. How come it get 3 positive roots??

Comment: U didn't say anything about positive roots!!

Comment: A polynomial of degree $n$ can have anywhere between $0$ and $n$ positive roots. And $2x^3-x^2+2x-5$ only has one positive root, not $3$.

Comment: oh! Book has got typo!! Got it. Thanks for ur time.